# `.split` method in clojure returns unexpected results

Tags: string, clojure

For part of a class project I need to read in a file representing a graph in Clojure. Here is a [link to](http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/~fmascia/files/DIMACS/C125.9.clq) an example file. The file structure for all the files I could possibly read in are such

```
c Unknown number of lines
c That start with "c" and are just comments
c The rest of the lines are edges
e 2 1
e 3 1
e 4 1
e 4 2
e 4 3
e 5 1
e 5 2
```

The issue that I am having is trying to `split` a line based on spaces. In my REPL I have done

```
finalproject.core> (.split "e 1 2" " ")
#<String[] [Ljava.lang.String;@180f214>
```

Which, I am not sure what it means exactly.. I think it refers to a memory locations of a `String[]` I am not sure why it is displayed like that though. If the insert a `#` in front of the split string, which I think denotes it is a regular expression I receive an error

```
finalproject.core> (.split "e 1 2" #" ")
ClassCastException java.util.regex.Pattern cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Currently my entire implementation of this module is, which I am pretty sure will work if I could properly use the `split` function.

```
(defn lineToEdge [line]
  (cond (.startsWith line "e")
        (let [split-line (.split line " ")
              first-str (split-line 1)
              second-str (split-line 2)]
          ((read-string first-str) (read-string second-str)))))

(defn readGraphFile [filename, numnodes]
  (use 'clojure.java.io)
  (let [edge-list 
        (with-open [rdr (reader filename)]
          (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
           (lineToEdge line)))]
    (reduce add-edge (empty-graph numnodes) edge-list)))
```

I have not had a chance to test `readGraphFile` in any way but when I try to use `lineToEdge` with some dummy input I receive the error

```
finalproject.core> (lineToEdge "e 1 2")
ClassCastException [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

Suggestions as to where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following, your return value is an Array of type String.

```
finalproject.core> (.split "e 1 2" " ")
#<String[] [Ljava.lang.String;@180f214>
```

To use it more conveniently in Clojure, you can put it into a vector:

```
user=> (vec (.split "e 1 2" " "))
["e" "1" "2"]
```

You can also use the built in `clojure.string` namespace:

```
user=> (require '[clojure.string :as string])
nil
user=> (string/split "e 1 2" #" ")
["e" "1" "2"]
```

The source of your stack trace is here:

```
(let [split-line (.split line " ")
      first-str (split-line 1)
      second-str (split-line 2)] ...)
```

This gets a String Array, via `.split`, then attempts to call it as if it were a function. Perhaps you meant to use `get` here to access an element of the List by index? `(get split-line 1)` will get the element from `split-line` at index 1, etc.

You'll see another problem here:

```
((read-string first-str) (read-string second-str))
```

If I am reading your code properly, this will end up calling a number as if it were a function, with another number as an argument. Perhaps you intend to return a pair of numbers?

```
[(read-string first-str) (read-string second-str)]
```

Comment: What `split` function is being used if not the `clojure.string.split` when `(require '[clojure.string :as string])` is not used? // What is the difference between `(use 'clojure.java.io)` and `(require '[clojure.string :as string])`?

Comment: the `.` notation indicates a method call, it's the native java split

Comment: The value returned by `String.split` is actually an array of strings – `String[]`, or `[Ljava.lang.String;` in lower-level JVM lingo ­– and not a `java.util.List`. Also, `(vec (.split …))` is preferable here, because for short vectors (up to 32 items long) `vec` simply wraps a vector around the array (using it as the tail of the new vector). This is of course only ok if the array is known to be safe from modification, which in this case it is. (`string/split` is implemented using a Clojure implementation detail that works like `vec` in this respect.)

Comment: the difference between `require` and `use` is covered in depth elsewhere, but the short version is that we prefer `require` because it makes where functions come from more explicit, and avoids issues with multiple namespaces having different definitions with the same names